# Fallout:NV - technical issues

Tags: xbox-360, fallout-new-vegas

I was reading a review of Fallout: New Vegas, because I am planning to buy the game (for Xbox 360). But I was very disappointed when I learned that there are many bugs and glitches in the game. The review I read is [here](http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/rpg/falloutnewvegas/review.html).

Is this true? If so, is there any chance this gets fixed somehow? I do not know if it is possible to patch a game on Xbox like it is on PC. While I will probably still buy the game, I am wondering whether or not I should be prepared for a buggy gameplay experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New Vegas definitely has more than its fair share of bugs. In my 300+ hours with the game so far, I've encountered numerous freezes (which lock up the entire 360). I do not know if they corrupted my auto-save file or not, as I save frequently -- alternating save locations every few hours (or major milestone).

On the 360, version 1.2.031 has just been released. This patch cleared up numerous [bugs and glitches](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_patch_1.2.0.285), including some of the most severe.

Some tips to reduce your likelihood of encountering severe bugs:

- Save early, save often, use at least two save slots, alternating between them every few hours or major milestone. (Don't alternate every save -- what if you accidentally created the circumstances for the bug prior to your earliest?)
- Preload the game onto your XBox hard drive. If nothing else, it should help with load times. (I don't find most of the load times unbearable, except loading The Strip.)
- Don't play continuously for more than 4 hours or so without rebooting your XBox. Plus, you should take breaks anyway. :)
- Play connected to Live, at least the first time, so the patch is pushed down to you.

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of answer i was looking for. I do not expect the game to be polished to perfection, but at least some patches are being released, thats good news!

Answer (score 3):

The game has many bugs, from mildly annoying to game-breaking. It is possible to install first party patches on Xbox (and PS3 too), and some patches have already been released for all platforms, fixing many issues. All you have to do to install the patch is boot up your game while connected on Xbox Live and the console will prompt you to update the game.

Even so, it is not likely that every bug will be fixed - Fallout 3 was released in 2008 and still has bugs. Some were fixed through patches and some were fixed in the "Game of the year" edition, but not all.

Just so you know what you can expect, here are some of the bugs I have experienced. I have been playing the game in the last few days and have around 30 hours of gameplay:

- The game has freezed twice, forcing me to turn off my console. At the second time this happened, my autosave got corrupted.
- Sometimes, after killing some enemies that were torned to pieces, their body parts started jiggling constantly.
- Sometimes the camera zooms slightly with no reason.
- In some large areas with lots of NPCs, I have experienced some slowdowns in the first seconds after being spawned there.
- Sometimes, the loading times were too long.

The last two weren't experienced during my playthrough of Fallout 3, but the first two were. About the save corruption, that's a good reason why you should save often.

Even so, I still recommend the game. Fallout 3 also had many bugs and I still loved it. I'm loving New Vegas too.

Comment: One note, not sure why, but I play New Vegas on PS3 and I've yet to have my autosave corrupted, but **always** I usually end up stopping play at about 3 hours cause the game freezes up. It doesn't matter what I'm doing or anything. I end up having to restart the game every 3 hours. But I've never lost my autosave.. regardless, I save often anyway